# Non cap sensitive search C#

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, string, search

I want to do a search of a list of strings, non cap sensitive.

Have tried .Contains and ==

Is there a method to do this, or would I have to convert the entire list of strings to noncaps, then search?

Cheers!

Comment: I think you meant to write a "case insensitive" search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it.

```
var answer = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals("test", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: You will end up with NullReferenceException here easily when item is null.

Comment: Do this to make it null safe: `"test".Equals(item, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: where does FirstOrDefault come from

Comment: @Andrew, for this particular sample it will work. But you cannot make it null safe that way if both instance and argument can be null. So it is better to use String.Compare.

Comment: FirstOrDefault is an extension method in System.Linq.Enumerable

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use C# 3:

```
var all = new [] {"A", "a", "AB", "aB", "Ab". "Etc"};
var searchItem = "A";
var found = all.Where (x => string.Compare(x, searchItem, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);

foreach(var foundItem in found)
  Console.WriteLine(foundItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [String.IndefOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) with the StringComparison argument set?  Alternatively, build a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use String.ToUpper() to compare as non sensitive.  (Just uppercase both strings you're comparing).

Or there are more advanced string comparison helpers in the .net lib:

See:
http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_How_perform_a_case_insensitive_string_comparison

Comment: This generally isn't a good idea, especially if you making many comparisons. Because strings are immutable a temporary string must be created to make the comparison.